# Proper way of adding custom code to vendor module?

Tags: magento2, model, extend, vendor

Is there a guide somewhere to overriding, extending or otherwise adding to the composer module sets that show up in `/vendor/`?

I've run into a couple of scenarios where I just have to make a few small modifications to Models and/or add custom phtml templates to views in some of the existing `/vendor/magento/module-*` packages. I know for regular site content, you can do the views in a custom theme, but in this particular case, we need to add a custom email template to `module-sales`.
Also, rather than add the complication of another extension to increase the flexibility of the filters in those templates, I would like to add an equivalent twig-like `number_format()` method for formatting values with trailing decimals.

But I'm not sure how I would extend the Model or where to put the custom views.
As stated, in this particular instance I need to add the custom view to `vendor/Magento/module-sales` and modify/extend the Model in `vendor/Magento/module-email/Model/Template`

Any help is appreciated.